# Changing the priority of children in a Composite

Tags: java, swt

I have a `Composite` called display that has children elements placed in an absolute layout. Throughout my program, these children can move around on the composite and overlap. I want to create a "priority" so I can choose which children are drawn on top of other elements. The children are a custom class named `Llama` I made that extends `Canvas`. I have an integer field that stores their priority, but I don't know how to make them display in the order I want them to display (based on the integer field). Here's an image of the program displaying what I mean by overlap.

[image]

Basically, they automatically choose an order of display based on the order they were added to the composite (as far as I can tell). How can I change that order to fit my priority field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`Control.moveAbove()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html) and `moveBelow()`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had seen that before, but didn't think it applied here. It works though!